# manipulating Django database directly

Tags: django

I was wondering this could produce any problem if I directly add rows or remove some from a model table. I thought maybe Django records the number of rows in all tables? or this could mess up the auto-generated id's?

I don't think it matters but I'm using MySql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not a problem because Django does the same that you do "directly" to the database, it execute SQL statements, and the auto generated id is handled by the database server (MySql server in this case), no matter where that SQL queries comes from, whatever it is Mysql Client or Django.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can have Django work on a pre-existing database (one that wasn't created by Django), I don't think you will have problems if you access/write the tables of your own app (you might want to avoid modifying Django's internal tables like `auth`, `permission`, `content_type` etc until you are familiar with them)

When you create a model through Django, Django doesn't store the count or anything (unless your app does), so it's okay if you create the model with Django on the SQL database, and then have another app write/read from that same SQL table

If you use Django signals, those will not be triggered by modifying the SQL table directly through the DB, so you might want to pay attention to side effects like that.

Your RDBMS handles it's own auto generated IDs and referential integrity, counts etc, so you don't have to worry about messing it up.